# Azure Data Lake Store bandwidth throttling limits

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

ADLS seems to implement some bandwidth limits. Does these apply equally to anyone accessing the data? (Is there a difference between an HDInsight cluster and ADL Analytics)?

In what range is this bandwidth and how is it determined?

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-performance-tuning-mapreduce#limitations) some HDInsight limits are mentioned.
[Here](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2017/2017_03_09/USQL_Release_Notes_2017_03_09.md) some U-SQL limits are mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADLS can scale to provide the bandwidth needed by all analytics workloads. The "limits" as mentioned in the articles are internal configurations which are high and sufficient to meet the default requirements of most common workloads. We do not recommend making design decision based on these configuration.

If you experience throttling errors and see lower performance as a result, please contact support. An ADLS team member will engage with you to help with your application.